# Set preview window mazimized by default in TexWorks

Tags: texworks

I'm writing a LaTeX document in TeXWorks and it's extremely annoying that everytime I compile, and get a preview (to see how the changes affect in the document) the preview window, wich I get by pressing control+t (I have windows 7) it's small and at the right, only occupying half of the screen. For seeing correctly the document I need to maximize that window always, because in that size all lines are cut in half and you can't see your document.
I need some preference setting for displaying preview in full screen (maximized) by default everytime I compile my LaTeX document.
This is not a useless complain, I'm compiling so frecuently and I have to move the mouse to the tiny "maximize" button at the corner, and press it, wich is annoying since is so little and it's hard and tiring to do it every 30 seconds.
If anybody could find a better way to do this I would be very thankful.

Comment: I am having the same problem! Did you find a solution? :)

Comment: @H.R. I don't remember now if I did.